# Does Java (J2ME) emulation information belong to Retrocomputing?

Tags: discussion, scope

Does Java (J2ME) emulation belong to Retrocomputing? I have some information on how to emulate a specific brand's flavour of J2ME via their proprietary products, and I would like to publish it somewhere

Back 10-20 years ago J2ME software was the "way to go" for much of the mobile devices, quickly fading away ion the early 2010s.

But J2ME emulation, at least in my mind, doesn't feel like the right fit for Retrocomputing. J2ME is inefficient (J2ME apps run in the inner Java VM) and not as old (as compared to, for example, ZX Spectrum. And while Retrocomputing's goal is to keep the old systems running, I believe the leftover J2ME apps were produced up until ~2016). But on the contrary, if J2ME isn't welcome, there doesn't appear any stackexchange-based website where any J2ME research can be published on, and it seems like Retrocomputing is the main harbour for the recreational emulation amongst the Stackexchange websites

So I would like to ask the senior members whether Java (J2ME) emulation information belong to Retrocomputing.

Comment: Java is not retrocomputing, hence Java ME isn't either even though it has been abandoned.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen x86 is not retrocomputing, hence Windows 95 isn't either even though it has been abandoned. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your point.)

Comment: The _emulators_ in themselves and running them would probably be retrocomputing.  To a Java programmer it is just another set of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. I dare even generalise it and say **using current languages (including old versions thereof) on obsolete targets is on-topic**, to the extent that the issues raised are specific to the retro platform in question.

This isn’t much different from how we treat [c](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) questions: although C is still in wide use, questions specific to C programming on retro platforms is on-topic, even if general C programming questions are not.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

- for one, J2ME is for much parts simply Java, so it would really need very specific J2ME topics to justify its inclusion.
- Further, emulations in themself are not really a topic for RC.SE. This has been discussed in many variations. Questions are only valid if their topic is the same as with the real machine.
- Which brings the next issue, J2ME isn't any classic machine. In fact it's not even an emulation, but a virtual machine application.
- And last, but maybe most important, RC.SE is about asking questions and collecting solutions in relation to real word problems. Asking pro forma questions, just to present some 'Answer' is not wrong, but not really satisfying either.

Having said that, I always found Java an interesting idea. It essential is the rediscovery of what UCSD Pascal was in the early 80s. Like this it belongs into a long list of ebedded virtual machines, which always were a fascinating topic - heck, even Tiny BASIC uses one to realize even compacter code.

Long story short: I love to learn more, but I do not feel that RC.SE is a good background for 'publishing'.

(Keep us informed where the 'publishing' will happen)

Comment: apologies for the delayed response
 
1. Not really actually, J2ME de facto encompasses a range of vendor-specific Java solution along the official J2ME. As counterexample, off the top of my head: [Munkiki Castles]( https://lostmediawiki.com/Munkiki%27s_Castles_(found_Nokia_3410_mobile_game;_2002) ) is one of the gens that took many years to be emulated. From my experience, also SE's "Super Real Tennis"
2-3. I understand
4. Understood and noted :) 
 
I'll likely publish on Superuser. Thanks for your interest, and wanting to learning more. Can't say more in comments, can we chat?

Comment: "Which brings the next issue, J2ME isn't any classic machine. In fact it's not even an emulation, but a virtual machine application" - actually, it's not even that: it's a collection of specifications. If you create a library based on those specifications, a J2ME application will be able to run with it.